# How to get the results to print out?/How to receive user input for variable 'x'?

Tags: python

I don't know how to receive user input or how to print out the results for this problem.

```py
def determine_grade(x):
    while x > -1 and x < 101:
        if x >= 90:
            return 'You got an A'
        elif x >= 80:
            return 'You got a B'
        elif x >= 70:
            return 'You got a C'
        elif x >= 65:
            return 'You got a D'
        elif x <= 65:
            return 'You got an F'
        else:
            return 'Terrible'

x = input("Type in your grade: ")
```

It just asks me to enter a grade, and then says finished with exit code 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
def determine_grade(x):
    while x > -1 and x < 101:
        if x >= 90:
            return 'You got an A'
        elif x >= 80:
            return 'You got a B'
        elif x >= 70:
            return 'You got a C'
        elif x >= 65:
            return 'You got a D'
        elif x <= 65:
            return 'You got an F'
        else:
            return 'Terrible'
x = input("Type in your grade: ")
print(determine_grade(int(x)));
```

the input value's type default is `string` before you pass it to `determine_grade`, you must convert it to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`x = input("Type in your grade: ")` => Store your input as a `string`

`def determine_grade(x):` => use this function by calling it `determine_grade(int(x))` - convert `str` to `int` before use `x` as an input

Ex:

```py
>>> x = input("Type in your grade: ")
Type in your grade: 2
>>> x
'2'
>>> determine_grade(int(x))
'You got an F'
```

Answer (score 0):

After this line `x = input("Type in your grade: ")` call the function with the `variable x` as the parameter. you have to first convert the datatype of the x variable to int as the `input` function returns the user input in string format. Use the `int` function to convert to string.

```
x = input("Type in your grade: ")
determine_grade(int(x))
```

alternatively you can use `print` to display the output

```
print(determine_grade(int(x)))
```